# Return random event out of last 2 events

Tags: random, complex-event-processing, esper, epl

Assume the following Esper events ([Esper Tryout page](https://esper-epl-tryout.appspot.com)):

```
StockTick={symbol='event1', price=1}
t=t.plus(10 seconds)
StockTick={symbol='event2', price=2}
t=t.plus(10 seconds)
StockTick={symbol='event3', price=3}
t=t.plus(10 seconds)
StockTick={symbol='event4', price=4}
```

*I would like to return a **random** out of the last two events every 3 seconds.*

I started with the following try but it does not work because the random variable never changes once it is initialized.

```
create schema StockTick(symbol string, price double);
create variable int size = 2;
create variable int rand = cast(Math.random()*size, int)+1;
@Name('Out') 
select prevtail(price) from StockTick#length(rand) output every 3 seconds;
```

I am grateful about any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could think of a bunch of possible ways.

- turn off the cache (http://esper.espertech.com/release-7.0.0/esper-reference/html_single/index.html#config-engine-expression-udfcache)
- or declare a variable of type Random
- or use a JavaScript script
- or have a user-defined function
- or use a custom aggregation function

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Assume I would ike to work with a variable of type Random:
I am looking for a statement which selects a random one of the last two events. 
`create schema StockTick(symbol string, price double);
create variable int size = 2;
create variable int rand = cast(Math.random()*size, int)+1;

@Name('Out') 
select prevtail(price) from StockTick#length(rand) output every 3 seconds;` This statement does not work, because the Random variable only seems to get initiated once and never changes. Could you think of a working solution?